# How to query based on a field but ignoreCase using QueryCriteriaUtils

Tags: corda

The code below will compare the value in the column but it is case-sensitive. How do I levarage on Corda's existing API to query based on a field but ignoring case.

```
searchCriteria =
builder { BondContract.BondEntity::customerName.`in`(listOf(name1, name2)) }
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Corda 3.2, the vault query API does not allow you to compare two strings in a case-insensitive way.